# How do I show that a given value is an eigenvalue of matrix A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have been given a 3x3 matrix 'A' and a value 'v'. I have to show that v is an eigenvalue of matrix A. How do I start?

And also, how to I determine all the eigenvectors that corresponding to v?

Comment: Find the kernel of $A-vI$, and show it contains a nonzero vector. "All eigenvalues" are in fact all those nonzero vectors.

Comment: Just solve the linear problem $Ax = vx$, where the unknown is the vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$. If you find such an $x$, it is an eigenvector.

Comment: @HerbertQuain: $x\neq0$

Comment: Yes, obviously.

Answer (score 3):

Substitute the value into the characteristic equation $\mathrm{det}(A-\lambda I)=0$ and see if it works out.